# How to set LOGIN_URL variable in Django settings so it doesn't redirect anywhere while not logged in

Tags: django, django-urls, django-authentication

When trying to access url `get_room_messages` if user is not logged in `@login_required` redirects him to: `/accounts/login/?next=/get_room_messages`
(as specified in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL))

I want it to do nothing (or redirect to the original url, in this example `/get_room_messages`). I don't want to hardcode it like `@login_required(login_url='/get_room_messages')`, ideal solution would be to get somehow original url and pass it into `@login_required()` decorator.

```
@login_required() 
def get_room_messages(request):
    user_id = request.user.user_ID
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=user_id)
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: just `@login_required`, remove the parentheses

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. If you want to display the same URL with different content dependent on whether user is authenticated or not - remove `@login_required` and put accoding if-else loginc inside a view method. And/or template code. If being _logged in_ to access a particular page is not required then why would you use `login_required`?